# Find a family of polynomials with these conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am working over the real numbers and trying to find polynomials $f_n$  for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

1. $f_n(0)=n$
2. $\mid f_n \mid \leq 1$ on the interval $[1,2]$

This should be fairly simple but I can't come up with a definition for the $f_n$ .

Comment: The polynomials $x^n$ would work if you were asking $f_n(2) = 2^n$ and $|f_n(x)| \leq 1$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Can you modify these slightly by squeezing and translating to solve your question?

Comment: @Raoul Thank you! I managed to construct what I am looking for with your help. Just out of curiosity, do you think it is necessary that the degree of the $f_n$ is unbounded?

Comment: In short: yes. I give a detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer the follow-up question of whether this is possible with bounded degree, and the answer is no.

To see this, assume the degree is bounded by $d$. Consider $\mathcal{P}_d$ the space of polynomials of degree $\leq d$, with the the norm
$$
\| P \| = \sup_{k=0,\dots,d} |a_k|
$$
where $P = a_0 + a_1 X + \cdots + a_d X^d$.

Now, take $\varphi$ the mapping from $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ to $\mathcal{P}_d$ that takes a $(d+1)$-tuple $(x_0,\dots,x_d)$ and returns the polynomial $P \in \mathcal{P}_d$ such that
$$
P(1+i/d) = x_i, \quad i  = 0, 1, \dots, d.
$$
It is well-defined by Lagrange interpolation, and is linear. As we are in finite dimension, then it is continuous. Therefore, the image by $\varphi$ of the compact set $[1,2]^{d+1}$ bounded, say by $K$. In particular, if $P = a_0 + a_1 X + \cdots + a_d X^d$ and $|P(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in [1,2]$, then
$$
|a_i| \leq K, \quad i  = 0, 1, \dots, d.
$$
But then also $|P(0)| \leq K$, so you could not get what $P(0) = n$ if $n$ is large enough and $d$ is fixed.

Comment: Very nice. Now I also know why one of my approaches didn't work, since I tried to take $f_n$ to be the lagrange interpolation of the points $(0,n)$, $(1,1)$ and $(2,0)$ (I was hoping this to be monotone on $[1,2]$ but for high enough values of $n$ the extreme point of the parabola moved below $2$). Thanks again for the insight.